# .htaccess folder to index.php and file to file

Tags: php, json, .htaccess

I'm creating a API for a specific part of my webapplication. The API is located in the subfolder API. See the folder structure below:

```
- API
  - cars
     - index.php
     - count.php
```

However, now the tricky part. Customers will be requesting endpoints that end with JSON:

cars.json => cars/index.php
cars/count.json => cars/count.php

I'm not an expert in rewrites. But is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cars\.json$ /cars/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cars/count\.json$ /cars/count.php [NC,L]
```

The first Rule rewrites **cars.json** to **cars/index.php** and the second Rule Rewrites **cars/count.json** to **cars/count.php** .

Comment: I've placed the .htaccess file in the API directory and now it throws an internal server error. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: probably because the path the user request is much longer. is it `http:example.org/api/cars.json`

Comment: True, full path is https://gate.carsdomain.com/branche/api/cars.json and https://gate.carsdomain.com/branche/api/cars/count.json. So where should I place the .htaccess and is that one still correct?